# How do I show a hyperlink in a PHP if statement in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add the following rollover image with a link inside of a PHP if statement.

but the hyperlink disappears when it is executed

```
<?php
      if(file-info) {
        echo " <a href="<?php the_field('file-info'); ?>">Access Application</a>";
      } else {
        echo "You are logged in!";
      }
?>
```

and

```
<?php if(file-info): ?>
<span class="rcg-line"><a href="<?php the_field('file-info'); ?>">
                       Access Application</a></span>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried using both examples above and it doesn't seem to work.

**update**

- I'm using the advanced custom fields plugin for wordpress.
- file-info is the varible its looking for in which the user entered and the_field is whats used to call it i guess

Comment: What is `file-info`.  A constant?  I'd start by turning on error reporting so you can be informed re. all the syntax /parse errors you are probably generating.

Comment: what does the `the_field` function do/return?

Comment: I think it should be `$the_field`   , or otherwise , the real field name that you are calling ... same for `file-info` there is no function or constant on that name either in wordpress, nor in the custom fields plugin. maybe `get_field('file-info')`

Comment: seems i was wrong , `the_field` is somehow a function in ACF . but still it is called wrongly. I think you lack some basic `PHP` knowladge.  see @ficuscr answer and read some docs ( also PHP )

Answer (score 1):

If the `the_field` function returns the desired value as a string, you need to echo it, and don't forget that HTML will want quotes around the value:

```
 echo " <a href='"<?php echo the_field('file-info'); ?>"'>Access Application</a>";
```

In your second example you will also want to put quotes around the value, and if `the_field` doesn't echo the value to the client, you'll need to echo it's return:

```
<a href='"<?php echo the_field('file-info'); ?>"'>
                   Access Application</a>
```

Edit: If the `the_field` function is properly emitting the value, omit the `echo` in each example.

Comment: Hmm. I will try that give me a few to test

Comment: You should **never** `echo` `the_field()`, as that function already echoes a value.

Comment: sure, hence the conditional in the first line: 'If the `the_field` function returns the desired value as a string'.  If the `the_field` function actually sends the data to the output stream, don't echo its return.

Comment: from [docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)  `the_field` Displays the value of the specified field. (this is the same as `“echo get_field($field_name)”)`

Answer (score 1):

So OP is talking about: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Try this...

```
<?php if(get_field('file-info')): ?>
    <span class="rcg-line">
      <a href="<?php the_field('file-info'); ?>">Access Application</a>
    </span>
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- Else case HTML would go here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Looks like `the_field` must call `echo`.

Seems like there are docs on the vendors page.  You need to unserstand distinction of 'string' literal and a variable.  Also `var_dump` is your friend.  Finally, please look at other posts which discuss how to enable PHP error reporting.  Will save us all a lot of time.

Comment: No.  Going off the code I see on vendor page I see: `<h2><?php the_field('sub_heading'); ?></h2>`... honestly who up-voted this question 3 times :) ? - ohh, @mevius I mean to say "The code must be calling echo because we do not need to" - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: it was I who was reading the sentence incorrectly. Whoops. Carry on.

Comment: awesome,  this worked perfectly.  thanks a million and everyone else who commented.